# Hibernate v3.6 : Issue with the EntityManager method "refresh"

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, jpa-2.0, entitymanager

The following code throws an exception when invoking "em.refresh(p)":

```
1: EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
2: em.getTransaction().begin();
3:
4: Product p = new Product("J&D", 35.0,"Whisky");
5: em.persist(p);
6:
7: em.refresh(p);
8: em.getTransaction().commit();
9: em.close();
```

When debugging the code, we see that Hibernate didn't write the record into the DB at line 6. He does is like foreseen - when it's required, not earlier.

At line 7, we get the following exception:
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: this instance does not yet exist as a row in the database

When we force Hibernate to flush the record into the DB at line 6, the INSERT is executed and no error occurs. We can do this by executing a select or just force the flush (with all consequences):

```
6 : em.createQuery("select p from Product p").getResultList();
6 : em.flush();
```

My question: should the method "refresh" not force Hibernate to write the record into the DB, as does the select or the flush statement wehn placesd before? (Might this be a bug?).

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Pierre

Answer (score 5):

> should the method "refresh" not force Hibernate to write the record into the DB, as does the select or the flush statement when placed before? (Might this be a bug?).

No, `refresh` should not flush changes since the whole point of `refresh` is to *revert any non-flushed changes made in the current transaction*. This is maybe better explained in the JPA wiki book than in the specification:

> The
>   [`EntityManager#refresh(Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh%28java.lang.Object%29)
>   operation is used to refresh an
>   object's state from the database. This
>   will revert any non-flushed changes
>   made in the current transaction to the
>   object, and refresh its state to what
>   is currently defined on the database.
>   If a `flush` has occurred, it will
>   refresh to what was flushed. Refresh
>   must be called on a managed object, so
>   you may first need to `find` the object
>   with the active `EntityManager` if you
>   have a non-managed instance.

So you should indeed `flush` after the `persist` if you want your code to work.

That being said, I don't see the point of doing a `refresh` just after a `persist` (assuming you flushed the changes), there is just nothing to refresh here. Maybe it's just a simplified example though.

#### References

- JPA 2.0 specification

  - 3.2.5 Refreshing an Entity Instance
- JPA Wiki book

  - [Refresh](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Persisting#Refresh)